# RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory when running command to train yolov5 on custom data

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, yolov5

the command

```
!cd yolov5 && python train.py --img 320 --batch 16 --epochs 5 --data dataset.yml --weights yolov5s.pt --workers 2
```

i get the error below when i run the command above

```
train: weights=yolov5s.pt, cfg=, data=dataset.yml, hyp=data\hyps\hyp.scratch-low.yaml, epochs=5, batch_size=16, imgsz=320, rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, noval=False, noautoanchor=False, noplots=False, evolve=None, evolve_population=data\hyps, resume_evolve=None, bucket=, cache=None, image_weights=False, device=, multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, optimizer=SGD, sync_bn=False, workers=2, project=runs\train, name=exp, exist_ok=False, quad=False, cos_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, patience=100, freeze=[0], save_period=-1, seed=0, local_rank=-1, entity=None, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, artifact_alias=latest, ndjson_console=False, ndjson_file=False
github: up to date with https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 
YOLOv5  v7.0-295-gac6c4383 Python-3.11.7 torch-2.2.1+cu118 CPU

hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.5, cls_pw=1.0, obj=1.0, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0
Comet: run 'pip install comet_ml' to automatically track and visualize YOLOv5  runs in Comet
TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs\train', view at http://localhost:6006/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\farir\yolov5\train.py", line 848, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "C:\Users\farir\yolov5\train.py", line 623, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\farir\yolov5\train.py", line 188, in train
    ckpt = torch.load(weights, map_location="cpu")  # load checkpoint to CPU to avoid CUDA memory leak
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\farir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1005, in load
    with _open_zipfile_reader(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\farir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 457, in __init__
    super().__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

i want to able to train the model and and then use it for detection on custom classes